# Strategy to scale a comparison table query and load time

Tags: mysql, index-tuning, scalability

given a product table

```
PRODUCT
id   some_column
1    10
2     2
3     8
```

when comparing all them I get a triangular matrix that I load from a csv file

```
COMPARISION
id  product_left  product_right   result
1              1              2        3
2              1              3        8  
3              2              3        2
```

where I want to perform a query that returns all the best **n** comparisons for a given product

```
SELECT * FROM COMPARISION WHERE ( product_left = 1 OR product_right = 1 ) ORDER BY result DESC LIMIT n
```

I've made an index for **product_left** and another for **product_right** column

But I'm not convinced that it will scale for tens of thousands products

ie:
20k products will produce ~200 million comparisons
the load takes 15 hours in regular desktop computer
and it will get slower to load with more indexes

so, which should be the best strategy to scale it?

- partitioning
- do a different query
- index the result column to help order by clause
- ...

you can find the solution here
https://github.com/rubentrancoso/cosinsimilarity

Comment: When you load a file, do you add the data to what's been loaded in the past, and process all of it? or, do you load an process a file (or, if appropriate, a batch of files) independently of what you loaded the last time you ran the process? If the latter, you might want to try loading the data without the indexes (leave on a clustered index, if you have one), and then add the indexes after the data's been loaded. This can be faster, sometimes.

Comment: If you will actually be running queries specifying one and only one product ID at a time, then adding the result column to both indexes (sorted in descending order) would almost certainly improve query performance. It might help even if you're querying multiple product IDs (but not as much).

Comment: Also, you might try splitting your query into two (one just looking at `product_left`, the other at `product_right`) combining the top results, and seeing what that does to performance. Check query plans too. This might get MySQL to use your indexes; when it has to look at `product_left` and `product_right` for every entry anyway, it might decide a table (or clustered index) scan would be better, whereas in actuality the checks of the two indexes would turn out to be faster. (Note that, in most cases, a query optimizer does make good choices - however, there are always exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

This will probably run faster:

```
( SELECT * FROM Comparision WHERE product_left  = 1
           ORDER BY result DESC  LIMIT n
)
UNION DISTINCT
( SELECT * FROM Comparision WHERE product_right = 1
           ORDER BY result DESC  LIMIT n
)
ORDER BY result DESC  LIMIT n
```

If there is no change of fetching the same row from the two `SELECTs`, change to `UNION ALL` to be a little faster.

Have these two 'composite' indexes:

```
INDEX(product_left,  result)
INDEX(product_right, result)
```

Yes, the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` are duplicated.  If you also need `OFFSET`, then it gets more complex, but still possible.

Why?  With the indexes I gave you, each `SELECT` will optimally filter (`WHERE`) and sort (`ORDER BY`), thereby touch only `n` rows.  Then the `UNION` puts together the 2*n rows, re-sorts and delivers the desired `n`.

With just `INDEX(product_left)` it will gather all the `1` rows, sort them and peel off `n` -- slower.

Without the `UNION`, the query will simply scan the entire table, ignoring your indexes (or any others).  (OK, there is a chance of some index being usable, but what I provided is better.)  Use `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to see what is going on.  (Ask for help it it is not obvious.)